# Закругленные края для фото

Tags: css

У меня есть карусель с разными фотографиями - разной высоты. Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы фото было с закругленными краями. Как это можно сделать?
То, как есть сейчас - скриншот ниже.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я вижу два варианта:
**1. Заполнять пространство картинкой**
Для `img` выставить свойства

```
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

**2. Не заполнять**
Добавить блок, который будет подстраиваться под высоту картинки.

```
.block_img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

$('.block_img').each(function(){
  var imgHeight = $(this).find('img').height();
  $(this).height(imgHeight);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Надо прописать в коде: `style`  `border-radius: 5px;`.  Можно также `5%`, но это уж грубо.

Comment: Он закруглит тогда по синему фону, а мне нужно image

Comment: @Валерий а зачем вы изображения с полями вставляете?

Answer (score 1):

Уберите поля у изображений и используйте `border-radius: 5px;`